# ssh_exchange_identification: connection closed by remote host VIRTUALBOX scenario

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, port-forwarding

On a virtual debian machine in VIRTUALBOX I type: ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 andrea@10.0.2.2, to make reverse tunneling and allow remote machine to see debian desktop.
on the remote machine (ubuntu) I've: ssh_exchange_identification: connection closed by remote host and connect to 10.0.2.15 port 22: failed
Can you help me please??

Comment: I've already modified my hosts.allow file adding the line: SSHD: ALL but nothing, ssh server still refuses to make my day a good day.

Comment: Is the "remote machine(ubuntu)" also running in VirtualBox?  What's the host OS, what kind of networking have you configured for the VMs?